# Unable to upload file on OpenShift

Tags: node.js, express, ckeditor, openshift

I'm using the CKEditor plugin to upload images to my OpenShift application but the application will not upload the files. It works fine locally, but I cannot determine what is causing the issue. It seems like it can't find the directory.

==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log <==
POST /uploader?CKEditor=content&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en - - ms - -
new Path: /var/lib/openshift/57cdb2770c1e660d0b000003/app-root/runtime/repo/routes/../public/uploads/test.jpg

{ err: 
   { [Error: ENOENT, open '/var/lib/openshift/57cdb2770c1e660d0b000003/app-root/runtime/repo/routes/../public/uploads/test.jpg']
     errno: 34,
     code: 'ENOENT',
     path: '/var/lib/openshift/57cdb2770c1e660d0b000003/app-root/runtime/repo/routes/../public/uploads/test.jpg' } }

Here is the route that handles the upload.

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multipart();
var fs = require('fs');

router.post('/', multipartMiddleware, function(req, res) {

  fs.readFile(req.files.upload.path, function(err, data) {

    var newPath = __dirname + '/../public/uploads/' + req.files.upload.name;

    console.log('new Path:', newPath);

    fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function(err) {

      if (err) console.log({
        err: err
      });
      else {
        html = "";
        html += "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        html += "    var funcNum = " + req.query.CKEditorFuncNum + ";";
        html += "    var url     = \"/uploads/" + req.files.upload.name + "\";";
        html += "    var message = \"Uploaded file successfully\";";
        html += "";
        html += "    window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(funcNum, url, message);";
        html += "</script>";

        res.send(html);
      }
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how OpenShift works but perhaps you didn't add your public/uploads directory to the project/repo/however it gets installed in the OpenShift servers.

Comment: Yup. That was the problem. When I deleted the files out of my local uploads directory, it removed it from OpenShift. I didn't think it would do that. Thanks for the quick response!